# QnA Bot Framework - How to do accents like "á"

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, azure-qna-maker

In my qna maker knowledge base I have this:

Question:
Hello

Answer:
Hello maría

But I got this answer on the bot: Hello mar&#237a . I tried many things and there is no results.

Thanks.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: skype for business

Comment: Can you try using the Bot Framework Emulator? I want to understand of the problem is coming from the Bot Builder, QnAMaker or SfB channel.

Comment: @FraciscoPonceGomez, only happens on channels like messenger, skype for business,etc. But in bot framework emulator works fine.

Comment: Hi @BrunoMarquez, I have created a bot and tried to reproduce your error but I see María correctly when using Facebook, Skype or any other channel. At this point I would check that the knowledge base has been correctly created in QnAMaker. This is my QnA knowledge base ```Question Answer Source
hi hello Editorial
hello hello María Editorial```

Comment: I would appreciate if you share how you call the qna service, because the way I do it maybe it's wrong and happens that "utf" problem.

Comment: Hi @BrunoMarquez, I make the standard call that comes with the sample QnA bot: public QnAMakerSettingsAttribute()
                : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnASubscriptionKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKbId"], "Hola, esto es un test!", 0.5). I will put my code in GitHub and share it here if that helps.

Comment: Hi, any news about it? Is there any reason to have encoding problems?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code where you are getting your response from QNA and pass it to code.

```
static void Main()
   {
      string unicodeString = "This string contains the unicode character Pi (\u03a0)";

      // Create two different encodings.
      Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
      Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

      // Convert the string into a byte array.
      byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

      // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
      byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

      // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
      char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
      ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
      string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);

      // Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
      Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", unicodeString);
      Console.WriteLine("Ascii converted string: {0}", asciiString);
   }
```

do let me know in case you need more help

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample here:
https://github.com/FranciscoPonceGomez/FranciscoQnAccents

It works in all channels for me. You should not have any problems with accents.

Knowledge Base:
[image]

You can try it here:
https://franciscoqnaccents.azurewebsites.net/

Let me know if there is anything in the code that doesn't make sense to you.

Regards,
Francisco